# Use dojo in Aurelia framework

Tags: javascript, dojo, integration, aurelia, arcgis

I have a Aurelia panel with systemjs as a module loader and in ECMAScript 6,7
we try to use ARCGIS (http://www.esri.com/en/arcgis/products/arcgis-pro/overview)
in our project but sadly it use dojo as a framework.
is there anyway to use dojo and Aurelia together in a panel or any way i can work with ArcGIS in Aurelia ? or you suggest me to switch to dojo to write this project 
its a new project but we use Aurelia before and it was great and we have too many custom  module for it and i am try to use it again if it possible
we use asp.net MVC in back end